# Eigenvalues and reducible polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $n \geq 3$. Is it true that an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with entries from a field has an eigenvalue if and only if every monic polynomial of degree $n$ is reducible? I believe it is true, but I couldn't come up with a proof. Is this known?

Comment: How are the matrix $\mathbf A$ and polynomials related?

Comment: @SewerKeeper As in matrices and their characteristic polynomials.

Comment: I think you should add it in your question. 
So the problem is " Is it true that any matrix $\mathbf A \in \mathbb F^{n \times n}$, where $\mathbb F$ is a field, has an eigenvalue if and only if his characteristic polynomial is reducible? "

Correct?

Comment: I'm confused. The $2\times 2$ identity matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ has an eigenvalue, but not every real quadratic polynomial is reducible.

Comment: @Qwertiops Ah yes, I forgot to mention this. I assume $n$ is at least 3.

Comment: @SewerKeeper It can be restated that way, but it's going to be equivalent to this problem because every monic polynomial is the characteristic polynomial of a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think my counterexample from the comments can be modified to work for all $n$. In fact we can show that neither implication is true.

**First Implication**

We claim that the existence of eigenvalues does not require every polynomial of degree $n$ to be reducible.

Take our field to be $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $A = I_n$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Then certainly $A$ has an eigenvalue (namely $1$).

However, we claim that there is always an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $n$. It suffices to show that $x^n - 2$ is irreducible, which is a trivial consequence of Eisenstein's criterion, since it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, hence over $\mathbb{Q}$, by a result sometimes called Gauss's Lemma. Alternatively, we can note that any nontrivial, proper factor of $x^n - 2$ would have constant coefficient $\pm \omega2^{a/n}$ for some $1 \leq a \leq n-1$ and some root of unity $\omega$, and no number of this form is ever rational.

**Second Implication**

We claim that if every polynomial of degree $n$ is reducible, it is possible for find an $n\times n$ matrix with no Eigenvalues.

Take our field to be $\mathbb{R}$, since every real polynomial of degree at least $3$ is reducible, and consider the $4\times 4$ matrix 
$$
A = \Bigg(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\Bigg)
$$

This matrix has characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(x) = (x^2+1)^2$, which has no roots, hence $A$ has no Eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm guessing the hope here is that every polynomial of degree $n$ being irreducible would imply that every polynomial of degree $n$ has a root. If this were true you would be able to conclude what you say.

However, this is not true: all polynomials of degree at least 3 over the real numbers are reducible, but in principle they might split into a product of irreducible quadratics (you may note that this implies the degree is even, and in fact odd degree polynomials have a real root).

On the matrix side of the picture, consider a block diagonal matrix where each block is a 2x2 matrix with no eigenvalues.